# Is there a command in bash to get the first n words instead of n lines similar to 'head -n'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

### I want to extract the first say 1M words from a large text file, can I do it in command line, instead of writing script?

Update: The data is one sentence per line, words are separated by white space, this structure should be preserved. I've done it with python with a word counter, just wondering whether it can be done with command line in a smarter way.

Comment: 1M(illion) ? Better do this with an enhanced script language like perl or python or whatever is installed already on the host.

Comment: Does whitespace in the input need to be preserved in the output?

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

```
tr '\n' ' ' < inputfile | cut -d' ' -f 1-1000000 > outputfile
```

Takes the first 1M words from inputfile (a word in this case is anything between two spaces) then outputs them on one line to outputfile. To have them on separate lines in the output (as per @triplee's comment):

```
tr ' ' '\n' < inputfile | head -1000000 > outputfile
```

Comment: I think I would add a `grep -v '^$'` to your second invocation to get rid of empty lines due to repeated spaces...